# Attach the button on the slider in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a button on top of my slider, so currently I am able to slide the animation from left to right and vice versa on the Button click.
But when I do that button is moving separately and feel like it is detached from slider. How to make it stick to slider any help would be great.

In this [EXAMPLE](http://usabilitypost.com/images/1104/css_slideout/index.html?), we can see how there is Feedback area which on hover slides the panel, so in my case that Feedback is a button should act the same way.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container" [@slide]="slideOpen ? true : false">
      <button [class.button-resize-expand]="!slideOpen"
              [class.button-resize-collapse]="slideOpen"
              (click)="togglePanel()">
        <i class="rotate-chevron" [class.rotate-clicked]="!slideOpen">{{slideOpen ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right'}}</i>
      </button>

      <div *ngIf="slideOpen"></div> 
</div>
```

TS:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      transition('* <=> *', [
        group([
          query(':enter', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
            animate('.3s', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
          ], {optional: true}),
          query(':leave', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
            animate('.3s', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
          ], {optional: true}),
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Comment: Can you provide a `stackblitz` for that ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-slider-animation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

This is what it is, just imagine if the button was on the yellow slide at right and middle and also moves along with the yellow slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [stackblitz-code](https://angular-slider-button.stackblitz.io) and it works, I used little CSS and another trigger element in angular animations.

[Here are resources which can be used for reference](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#wildcard-state)

HTML:

```
<div class="container" [@slide]="isOpen ? true : false">
  <button [class.button-resize-expand]="!isOpen"
          [class.button-resize-collapse]="isOpen"
          (click)="togglePanel()" [@openClose] ="isOpen ? 'open': 'closed'">
    <mat-icon class="rotate-chevron" [class.rotate-clicked]="!isOpen">{{panelExpanded ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right'}}</mat-icon>
  </button>

  <div *ngIf="isOpen" class="expandable-panel">
    <div class="current-task-info">
      So much data here damn!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
type isOpen = true|false;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      transition('* <=> *', [
        group([
          query(':enter', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
            animate('.3s', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
          ], {optional: true}),
          query(':leave', [
            style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
            animate('.3s', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
          ], {optional: true}),
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('openClose', [
      // ...
      state('open', style({
        animation: 'slidefront .3s linear 0s forwards'
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        animation: 'slideback .3s linear 0s backwards, bounce 1.5s'
      }))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isOpen = true;

  togglePanel(): void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes slidefront {
    from {left: 0%;}
    to {left: 80%;}
  }

  @keyframes slideback {
    from {right: 5%;}
    to {right: 80%;}
  }
```